# Adding the sum of the amount of numbers generated from a tuple

Tags: python

Basically what I'm trying to get at is below my program will generate a shuffle between the numbers in the tuple below, for example if it generates `[3,2,2,4,5,6]`, then the program would add up the values of 1 since there's no ones generated it would print as 0, then it would add up the values of 2 since there's 2 twos it would add up the value to 4 and print out a 4 etc etc.

```
from random import shuffle 

def make_roll() -> tuple:
    roll_number = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    shuffle(roll_number)
    print(f'Rolling the dice...{roll_number}')
```

Comment: `shuffle()` is just reordering your `roll_number` list, so `[3,2,2,4,5,6]` is an impossible result. You probably want to use [`choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices): `roll_number = choices(range(1, 7), k=6)`.

Comment: @john, there are plenty of methods, basically you need to iterate over `range(1, 7)` and multiply value on count of it's occurrences in `roll_number`. E.g. generate dictionary: `{i: i * roll_number.count(i) for i in range(1, 7)}`.

Comment: There are no tuples in your code. What **exactly** is *make_roll()* meant to do?

Comment: What exactly is the **full explicit** expected output for `[3,2,2,4,5,6]`?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a Counter object.

[Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects)

### **Code**

```py
from collections import Counter

lst = [4,3,3,2,2,2,1,1]
c = Counter()
for n in lst:        #creates a dictionary of occurences
  c[n] += 1

for i in set(lst):   #select numbers and * by occurrences
  print(i * c[i])
```

### **Result**

```
Counter({2: 3, 3: 2, 1: 2, 4: 1})

0
2
6
6
4
```

That way you could use something like `c.total()` to get the total number of rolls, or `c.update()` to update occurrences for a bonus roll e.g.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite unclear, but assuming you first generate a random set of dice roll, then want to count the point per face value.

```
from random import choices
from collections import Counter

rolls = choices(range(1, 7), k=6)
# [3, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6]

c = Counter(rolls)
out = [c[i]*i for i in range(1, 7)]  # generic: range(1, max(c)+1)

# [0, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
numbers = [3,2,2,4,5,6]
for i in range(1,max(numbers)+1):
    n = 0
    for j in numbers:
        if i == j: n+=j
    print(n)
```